# I need a script that deletes rows after a certain time period

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

is it possible to make a script to remove responses from spreadsheet that are over 3 weeks old?

this is the script that I tried that didn't work:

```
function duration() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var newData = new Array();
var now = new Date();
newData.push([("Timestamp") , ("First Name") , ("Last Name") , ("Homeroom")]);
for(i in data){
 var row = data[i]; if (now - row[0] < 300000) { newData.push(row); 
 } 
} 

sheet.clearContents(); 
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
```

Comment: Yes, you need to add a [time-driven (clock) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).  Then you'll need to be able to somehow filter by date.  Do a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Bgoogle-spreadsheet%5Ddelete+rows+date)

Comment: @SandyGood, I am unsure how to make it. I don't have experience making scripts so just wanted to ask if anyone knows a direct answer since I'm clueless on this sort of thing. I tried using one program that someone put, but it just deleted all the responses on form and it changed the top row to something different than what the responses are supposed to be.

Comment: @Lev Asking if it was possible is likely the wrong way to ask that. Is it possible suggests you just want a yes or no answer, rather than an actual solution.

Comment: @SandyGood, this is the script that I tried that didn't work:

function duration() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  var now = new Date();

  newData.push([("Timestamp") , ("First Name") , ("Last Name") , ("Homeroom")]);

  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    if (now - row[0] < 300000) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);

I am unsure about how to keep formatting when copy and paste to here.

Comment: @Lev, that belongs in your question. Click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30403294/edit)

Comment: @KevinB, I apologize I'm new to this site. I have seen people post comments with code. Can you recommend a way on how I should ask this question since I don't have experience programming and if I manually delete after 3 weeks, there ends up being a gap when a new person submits.

Comment: Yes, people somtimes post comments with code. But, it's not readable, especially when it's that much code. you can't format code properly in comments.

Comment: @KevinB, not sure. This was the code I used that just ends up deleting all my form responses and changes the information that I asked.

http://prntscr.com/7885ap

Comment: Added your code to the question

Answer (score 0):

This works.  I've tested it:

```
function duration() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  var now = new Date();

  var threeWeeksAgo = new Date();
  threeWeeksAgo.setDate(now.getDate() - 21);

  var theLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  newData.push(["Timestamp","First Name","Last Name","Homeroom"]);

  for(var i=0;i<theLastRow;i++){
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[0] > threeWeeksAgo) {
      newData.push(row); 
    }; 
  }; 

  sheet.clearContents(); 
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
};
```